# You fed me and my grandpa... with what? And why?

Tags: riddle, word

- You fed me inedible objects for... reasons.
- You made me spit out the objects too.
- You fed my grandpa with chunks.
- You fed me with slices.

Why did you feed us, and *what* did you feed us?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Video players or other devices for playing recorded media:
>
> - *You fed me inedible objects* : inserting the media
>
>   *You made me spit out the objects too* : ejecting the media
>
>   *You fed my grandpa with chunks* : Back in the day we had cassette tapes and tape drives
>
>   *You fed me with slices* : Today we can store things on *thin slices* like BluRay / DVD / CDs etc.